# Jquery is not loading in force.com edition

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, jquery, dynamic-visualforce

I have created calender using jQuery lib please find the code below:

It's working fine in developer Edition.
But same code if I copy in partner enterprise edition  it's not displaying information:

Vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="CalendarExample_Controller" action="{!pageLoad}" sidebar="false" showHeader="true">
    <link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarPrintCSS}" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{!$Resource.fullCalendarMinJS}"></script>
    <script>
        //We need to wrap everything in a doc.ready function so that the code fires after the DOM is loaded
        $(document).ready(function() {   
                        //Call the fullCallendar method. You can replace the '#calendar' with the ID of the dom element where you want the calendar to go. 
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                events:
                [
                    //At run time, this APEX Repeat will reneder the array elements for the events array
                    <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="e">


                        {
                            title: "{!e.title}",
                            Stage:"{!e.stage}",
                            start: '{!e.startString}',
                            end: '{!e.endString}',
                            url: '{!e.url}',
                            allDay: {!e.allDay},
                            className: '{!e.className}'
                        },
                    </apex:repeat>
                ]
            });

        });

    </script>
    <!--some styling. Modify this to fit your needs-->
    <style>
        #cal-options {float:left;}
        #cal-legend { float:right;}
        #cal-legend ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
        #cal-legend ul li {margin:0;padding:5px;float:left;}
        #cal-legend ul li span {display:block; height:16px; width:16px; margin-right:4px; float:left; border-radius:4px;}
        #calendar {margin-top:20px;}
        #calendar a:hover {color:#fff !important;}
        .fc-event-inner {padding:3px;}
        .event-birthday {background:#56458c;border-color:#56458c;}
        .event-campaign {background:#cc9933;border-color:#cc9933;}
        .event-personal {background:#1797c0;border-color:#1797c0;}
        .event-Asif {background:#00FF00;border-color:#1797c0;}
        .event-Asif1 {background:#1797c0;border-color:#cc9933;}
    </style>
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Asif Calender"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="calPanel">
        <apex:form >
            <div id="cal-options">
                <apex:commandButton value="{!IF(includeMyEvents,'Hide My Events','Show My Events')}" action="{!toggleMyEvents}"/>
            </div>
            <div id="cal-legend">
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="event-Asif1"></span>Tentative</li>
                    <li><span class="event-Asif"></span>Confirmed</li>
                    <!--    <li style="{!IF(includeMyEvents,'','display:none')}"><span class="event-personal"></span>My Events</li>-->
                </ul>
                <div style="clear:both;">
                    <!--fix floats-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;">
                <!--fix floats-->
            </div>
            <div id="calendar">
                <!--  <apex:datatable value="{!events}" var="e">
                    <apex:column > <a href="/{!e.Id}" id="{!e.Id}" onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!e.Id}').hide();" onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!e.Id}', '/{!e.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!e.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();" onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!e.Id}').hide();" onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!e.Id}', '/{!e.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!e.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">{!e.title}</a></apex:column>
                    </apex:datatable>-->
            </div>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class CalendarExample_Controller {

    public Boolean includeMyEvents {get; set;}
    public list<calEvent> events {get; set;}

    String dtFormat = 'EEE,d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z';

    public CalendarExample_Controller() {

        includeMyEvents = true;
    }
    public PageReference pageLoad() {
        events = new list<calEvent>();
        for (Contact cont : [select Id, Birthdate, FirstName, LastName from Contact where Birthdate != null]) {

            DateTime startDT = datetime.newInstance(Date.Today().Year(), cont.Birthdate.Month(), cont.Birthdate.Day());
            calEvent bday = new calEvent();
            bday.title = cont.FirstName + ' ' + cont.LastName + '\'s Birthday!';
            bday.allDay = true;
            bday.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
            bday.endString = '';
            bday.url = '/' + cont.Id;
            bday.className = 'event-birthday';
            events.add(bday);
        }


        for (Campaign camp : [select Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate from Campaign where IsActive = true]) {
            DateTime startDT = camp.StartDate;
            DateTime endDT = camp.EndDate;
            calEvent campEvent = new calEvent();

            campEvent.title = camp.Name;
            campEvent.allDay = true;
            campEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
            campEvent.endString = endDT.format(dtFormat);
            campEvent.url = '/' + camp.Id;
            campEvent.className = 'event-campaign';
            events.add(campEvent);
        }



        for (Opportunity camp : [select Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName from Opportunity where StageName = 'Closed Won']) {
            DateTime startDT = camp.CloseDate;
            calEvent campEvent = new calEvent();
            campEvent.title = camp.Name;
            campEvent.allDay = true;
            campEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
            campEvent.url = '/' + camp.Id;
            campEvent.className = 'event-Asif';
            events.add(campEvent);
        }


        for (Opportunity camp : [select Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName from Opportunity where StageName != 'Closed Won']) {
            DateTime startDT = camp.CloseDate;
            calEvent campEvent = new calEvent();
            campEvent.title = camp.Name;
            campEvent.allDay = true;
            campEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
            campEvent.url = '/' + camp.Id;
            campEvent.className = 'event-Asif1';
            events.add(campEvent);
        }


        if (includeMyEvents) {
            for (Event evnt : [select Id, Subject, isAllDayEvent, StartDateTime, EndDateTime from Event where OwnerID = :UserInfo.getUserId()]) {
                DateTime startDT = evnt.StartDateTime;
                DateTime endDT = evnt.EndDateTime;
                calEvent myEvent = new calEvent();

                myEvent.title = evnt.Subject;
                myEvent.allDay = evnt.isAllDayEvent;
                myEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
                myEvent.endString = endDT.format(dtFormat);
                myEvent.url = '/' + evnt.Id;
                myEvent.className = 'event-personal';
                events.add(myEvent);


            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference toggleMyEvents() {
        if (includeMyEvents) {
            includeMyEvents = false;
        } else {
            includeMyEvents = true;
        }
        pageload();
        return null;
    }

    public class calEvent {
        public String title {get; set;}
        public Boolean allDay {get; set;}
        public String startString {get; set;}
        public String endString {get; set;}
        public String url {get; set;}
        public String className {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `jQuery.noConflict()` and `apex:includeScript`. Check following  topics: [jQuery plugin noConflict](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25767/jquery-plugin-noconflict), [Page cannot use jQuery Plugin as it's registered with $ from Sidebar component](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46978/page-cannot-use-jquery-plugin-as-its-registered-with-from-sidebar-component)

Comment: I have added that still i cannot get the information

Comment: console log: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
Momentmin:6 Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
Momentmin:6 Deprecation warning: moment().zone is deprecated, use moment().utcOffset instead.

Comment: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1779
asifcalender?sfdc.tabName=01rO00000009Ewu&core.apexpages.devmode.url=1:1 GET https://login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png 404 (Not Found)
asifcalender?sfdc.tabName=01rO00000009Ewu&core.apexpages.devmode.url=1:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://cs5.salesforce.com/ui/core/activity/ActivityReminderRefreshPage?at=1424423554606. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://c.cs5.visual.force.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relevant difference between Developer Edition and Partner Enterprise Edition which lead to the effects you are describing.

However may aspects of the configuration and/or installed 3rd party apps may radically interfere with your javascript. So I would recommend, that you focus your attention on config+apps instead of the edition.

You might carefully inspect:

- sidebar, homepage-components, links, buttons
- chatter enabled in both orgs?
- differences in loaded java-scripts (I use firefox and JS-View to see, what is loaded at a glance)
- other differences in configuration

Keep in mind, that basically all "enterprise-alike" editions are the same. Both the Developer Edition and the Partner Enterprise Edition are nearly the same under the hood. Differences usually are configured by yourself or your co-admins...